# Суммировать значения select в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Прошу помощи
Есть форма:

```html
<div id="sum">
  <form>
    <select id="1" name="1">
      <option value="5">текст</option>
      <option value="4">текст</option>
    </select>
    <select id="2" name="2">
      <option value="3">текст</option>
      <option value="0">текст</option>
    </select>
    <select id="3" name="3" multiple>
      <option value="4">текст</option>
      <option value="9">текст</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="itog" id="itog" value="" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Нужно сложить значения всех выбранных select и select multiple, а итог вывести в input.

Comment: Покажите код, где Вы пытались выполнить сложение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('select').change(sum);

function sum(){
    let result=0;
    $('#sum').find('select').each(function(){
        let value = 0;
        if (typeof $(this).val() == 'object'){
          $.each($(this).val(), function(index, val) {
            value += val*1;
          });
        } else {
          value = $(this).val()
        }
        result+=value*1;
    });
    $('#itog').val(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sum">
  <form>
    <select id="1" name="1">
      <option value="5">текст</option>
      <option value="4">текст</option>
    </select>
    <select id="2" name="2">
      <option value="3">текст</option>
      <option value="0">текст</option>
    </select>
    <select id="3" name="3" multiple>
      <option value="4">текст</option>
      <option value="9">текст</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="itog" id="itog" value="" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Если выбрать сразу две опции в последнем селекте (зажав Ctrl) -> NaN

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME про ctrl ни чего нету в условии этого вопроса

Comment: Спасибо, к сожалению при выборе нескольких значений в select multiple не работает.

Comment: @MaximLensky так наличие multiple предполагает возможность выбрать несколько опций (или пусть аффтар поправит - но тогда странно, что такой элемент вообще есть)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME спасибо, исправил

Comment: @user305361 добавил multiple

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME вот этого я не знал ..сорри за непонятку ..